# Why doesnt my Firestore composite index work?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm relatively new to using firestore. I want to filter my collection using composite indexes but it doesn't seem to work? I'm not sure what went wrong. Here's my code:

```
Stream<List<Listing>> readListings() {
    DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.now();
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Listings')
        .where("expiryDate", isGreaterThan: currentDateTime)
        .where("isAvailable", isEqualTo: true)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) =>
            snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Listing.fromJson(doc.data())).toList());
  }
```

The error message is:

```
W/Firestore( 9339): (24.6.0) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(Listings where expiryDate>time(1686292045,716000000) and isAvailable==true order by expiryDate, __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/foodbridge-b1332/firestore/indexes?create_composite=ClFwcm9qZWN0cy9mb29kYnJpZGdlLWIxMzMyL2RhdGFiYXNlcy8oZGVmYXVsdCkvY29sbGVjdGlvbkdyb3Vwcy9MaXN0aW5ncy9pbmRleGVzL18QARoPCgtpc0F2YWlsYWJsZRABGg4KCmV4cGlyeURhdGUQARoMCghfX25hbWVfXxAB, cause=null}   
D/EGL_emulation( 9339): app_time_stats: avg=402.96ms min=14.32ms max=1517.38ms count=4
W/Firestore( 9339): (24.6.0) [WatchStream]: (aef561b) Stream closed with status: Status{code=CANCELLED, description=Disconnecting idle stream. Timed out waiting for new targets., cause=null}.
D/TrafficStats( 9339): tagSocket(136) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
```

However, I already created the index in firestore?
[screenshot of index in firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT3xh.png)

I tried adding sortby too but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You execute a query on the `listings` collection while your index is on the `HomePageAllAvailableListings` collection. You need to create the index for the `listings` collection by opening the URL provided in the error message.